# Is there a PhP wrapper of OpenBabel?

Tags: openbabel

We are using this for customer to generate images, but we have to serve the images in round-about way. It will be nice if OpenBabel gives us as Stream that can be redirected automatically.

Answer (score 0):

YES. You can use swig to compile it.

```
cmake sourcepath -DPHP_BINDINGS=ON -DRUN_SWIG=ON
```